# jQuery Chosen select. Есть ли аналог, или как сделать, чтоб в случае "no match" поле оставалось заполненным

Tags: jquery, select, chosen

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Есть ли готовый такой аналог, или как сделать, чтоб если в выпадающем списке "no match", т.е. ничего не нашли, то поле оставалось заполненным тем что мы вводили

Уже штук 5 аналогов посмотрел, везде то же самое, неужели то что я хочу так нетривиально...

Comment: "no match"? поместите минимум кода в вопрос

Comment: Igor, https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ вот примеры и код, сюда не получится вставить минимум кода

Comment: "no match" наверное